# Getting a syntax error when converting a string into an int

Tags: python, django

I am trying to convert a string into an int using the typecast "(int)". Here is what I am doing:

```
num = (int) request.POST['num']
```

Comment: Python is not C. Read some of the python beginner's guides.

Comment: what you are doing isn't Python, and how to do it is in every single Python beginners guide for the last 10+ years

Comment: [Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.org/) is a great book to get you started.

Comment: This wouldn't work even in C, you can't typecast arbitrary objects

Answer (score 9):

Try using the [`int()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int) instead.

```
num = int(request.POST['num'])
```